# Using NavigableMap inside NavigableMap

Tags: java, collections

I tried using `NavigableMap<K, V>` today, where `K` is also a `NavigableMap<K, V>` map. And implemented `NavigableMap<K, V>` using `TreeMap<K, V>`. Well, for the test, I decided to add a couple of elements to the main handle map. And these elements for handle `K` are a nested `NavigableMap<K, V>` for `K` and `V` a simple `Integer`, and for handle `V` is just `String`.

For a quick understanding what Im actually mean it's best to look at the code:

```
 
NavigableMap<NavigableMap<Integer, Integer>, String> handle = 
    new TreeMap<NavigableMap<Integer,Integer>, String>();
        
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> subMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
subMap.put(43787483,  0);
subMap.put(785845574, 1);
    
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> subMap2 = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
subMap2.put(78473374,  0);
subMap2.put(478374879, 1);
        
handle.put(subMap, "SubMap 1");
handle.put(subMap2, "SubMap 2");
```

But unfortunately, the code that is supposed to work normally crashes with the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (java.util.TreeMap and java.lang.Comparable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

at line

```
handle.put(subMap, "SubMap 1");
```

I of course understand that there is something related to the `Comparator<K>`, but the same test with a simple `NavigateMap<K, V>` works normally and without exceptions. This is the same example:

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> handle = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        
handle.put(0, "SubMap 1");
handle.put(1, "SubMap 2");
```

Do you have any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: NavigableMap is a subclass of SortedMap, which means its entries are sorted by keys.  How would your outer NavigableMap be sorted?  What is the ordering for the keys, which are themselves NavigableMaps?  (Do yourself a favor and write a separate class which encapsulates the Maps, while providing meaningful method names that indicate the type of data you’re dealing with;  a Map of Maps is hard to understand and hard to work with.)

Comment: In your mind, what is the order of maps? I'm not asking what is the order of the keys in a `NavigableMap<Integer, ?>`, what that the relative order of multiple such maps?

Comment: @VGR I have already done this creating my own maps (`MyMap`) that inherited from `NegativeMap` (inteface) and implementing these maps `MyMapImpl` (class) inherited from `TreeMap`. And it worked but not the way I needed it. I used the same example only with my own maps, but for some reason only one pair `K`, `V`was added to the main map, and when I tried to add another pair, it just wasn't added.

Comment: I’m almost sure this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Are you just using a Map as a list of pairs?  Or do you really intend to do a lookup with its `get` method?  What do the integer values mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since `TreeMap` does not implement `Comparable`, you need to specify your own `Comparator` to define how the keys should be ordered.

```
NavigableMap<NavigableMap<Integer, Integer>, String> handle = 
   new TreeMap<>(
      (map1, map2) -> {/*return 0 if equal, < 0 if map1 goes first, and > 0 otherwise*/}
);
```

Comment: Can show a detailed example I just don't really understand how to implement Comparators.

Comment: What is your criteria for ordering the maps?

Comment: Well, my idea was that the main `NavigateMap` represents a group of entities associated with their components, where components can be modified and store data. Where `K` is any `Map` contains entity pair-numbers (`K` - ID, `V` - number (for counting), and `V` is any `Map` contains components (`K` - ID, `V` - Data)

Comment: @KennyTutorials why do you think that the map key has to contain a “number (for counting)”? Do you understand that keys *must not* be modified, so changing this “number (for counting)” would break it? Besides that, you didn’t answer the question at all, what is your criteria for ordering the maps. If you can’t answer it, perhaps, you don’t need an ordering at all? Why do you insist on a `NavigableMap`, can’t a `HashMap` serve your task as well?